# Interface (wrapper) to SZIP from Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression

I'm looking for a (reliable) interface to **SZIP** (de)compressing library from Python.  I found [ricecomp-cfitsio](https://pypi.org/project/ricecomp-cfitsio/) and tried to use it, but I have no experience with the SZIP library or the Rice algorithm, and this package is far from being well documented.  So I end up with some arguments to the provided API for the decompression routines that work for some input data but not for others (and I get an exception "*Failure to decompress data*", but don't know why -- in fact, I get a `TypeError` exception "*Can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str*" when the former exception is raised, surely because I'm using this package with Python 3).

I would like to find a package that provides an API that calls directly the **SZIP** library.  I understand this can be done through a **Cython** module, and I'm trying hard to get it, but I have no experience at all with that, and I'm not getting as far as I need.